# I am looking for a solution to my plotting problem

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my data: dput(test_data):

```
structure(list(day = c("11. Februar", "12. Februar", "13. Februar", 
"14. Februar", "15. Februar", "16. Februar", "18. Februar", "19. Februar", 
"20. Februar", "21. Februar", "22. Februar", "23. Februar", "25. Februar", 
"26. Februar", "27. Februar", "28. Februar", "01. März", "02. März", 
"04. März", "05. März", "06. März", "07. März", "08. März", 
"09. März", "11. März"), mean_score = c(-0.0544601918465228, 
-0.0261774456521739, -0.0194014563106796, -0.0700457858769932, 
-0.0344666666666667, -0.0431649230769231, -0.0395243346007605, 
0.00460614406779661, -0.0536940711462451, -0.0243264444444444, 
-0.0295975683890577, -0.0554590509666081, -0.0600848484848485, 
-0.0214302375809935, -0.00898032490974729, -0.0516276397515528, 
-0.0820686330935252, -0.054661620294599, -0.049621686746988, 
-0.0169375654450262, -0.0215138719512195, -0.0119615160349854, 
-0.00512207207207207, -0.0409468584405753, -0.0158904621435595
)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000022386fef540>)
```

Now I want to plot this data with the following code:

```
test_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = mean_score)) +
  stat_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = "loess", se = FALSE, size = 2.5, color = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.08, 0.001), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = test_data$day, 
                   labels = ifelse(test_data$day == "27. Februar", "27. Februar", "")) +
  xlab(" ") +
  ylab("Sentiment Score") +
  ggtitle("Raiffi Verlauf über 30 Tage") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray80"))
```

The plot looks like this:

[image]

Now I can come to my question: Why is the x axis label "27. Februar" (german for "27 February") at the end of the plot? When you look at test_data you see that "27. Februar" is actually in the middle of the datatable. test_data starts at 11. Februar (11 Februray) and ends at 11. März (11 March). So, the plot above is not representing my data correctly. How can I correct this?

Thanks for your help.

Best,

Marsupilami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"27. Februar" appears towards the end of the plot because the x-axis is being sorted by `ggplot2`. If you remove the conditional labeling you'll see the axis starts with March:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

test_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = mean_score)) +
  stat_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = "loess", se = FALSE, size = 2.5, color = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.08, 0.001), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = test_data$day,) +
  xlab(" ") +
  ylab("Sentiment Score") +
  ggtitle("Raiffi Verlauf über 30 Tage") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray80"))
```

[image]

You can tell `ggplot2` that the day is an ordered variable with `factor(day, levels = day)`, and now the 27th of Feb appears where expected.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

test_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(day, levels = day), y = mean_score)) +
  stat_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = "loess", se = FALSE, size = 2.5, color = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.08, 0.001), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = test_data$day, 
                   labels = ifelse(test_data$day == "27. Februar", "27. Februar", "")) +
  xlab(" ") +
  ylab("Sentiment Score") +
  ggtitle("Raiffi Verlauf über 30 Tage") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray80"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that and appreciate your help.